# Does anyone know of a simple "You are here" Android Maps tutorial?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have been going through loads and loads of tutorials found through Google, loads of sample code, loads of ideas and I can't get them to work. There's something I'm not doing right every single time, so I want to start from scratch. Does anyone know of a simple "You are here" type of application. Something that will load Google Maps, and go to the user's location?

I have tried the tutorial from the Android API, but it doesn't tell the entire code, and I'm going wrong somewhere.

With a fresh tutorial I can solve my problem **and** learn. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well good timing - I just wrote a simple [tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/writing/my-map-location-tutorial-where-am-i/) with source code on my blog.  It creates a MapActivity and adds a MyLocationOverlay to the MapView.

Answer (score 0):

There is good tutorial on this topic in Reto Meier's book "Professional Android 2 Application Development". Sample project can be found on [wrox.com](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html), in Example projects file, Chapter 8 "Where Am I".